# Structured directories on ReactJS with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, directory, directory-structure

I trying to export all component from folder components, and I create index.js to export all component inside components folder, here's  my code :

```
// @flow

import Button from './Button/Button.component';
import Devider from './DividerComponent/Divider.component';
import Dropdown from './Dropdown/Dropdown.component';
import GeneralText from './GeneralTextComponent/GeneralText.component';
import IconButton from './IconButton/IconButton.component';
import InputDate from './InputDate/InputDate.component';
import InputText from './InputText/InputText.component';
import Toggle from './ToggleComponent/Toggle.component';
import Svg from './Svg/Svg.component';

export default {
  Button,
  Devider,
  Dropdown,
  GeneralText,
  IconButton,
  InputDate,
  InputText,
  Toggle,
  Svg
};
```

But, when I'm importing from "./components" there is error like this :

```
Failed to compile.

Attempted import error: 'Button' is not exported from './Components' (imported as 'Button').
ERROR in ./src/MockComponents.js 12:35-41
export 'Button' (imported as 'Button') was not found in './Components' (possible exports: default)

webpack compiled with 1 error
```

and here's my code when importing component from './components' :

```
import React from 'react'
import { Button   } from './Components'

const MockComponents = () => {
  return (
    <div>
        <Button/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default MockComponents
```

Thanks for helping me guys

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that you can export structured directories:

1. Since you want to import (for example the `Button`) as an object

```js
import { Button } from './Components'
```

You will also need to export it as an object using (should not be export default with an object)

```js
export { Button };

// Export whole object:
export {
  Button,
  Devider,
  Dropdown,
  GeneralText,
  IconButton,
  InputDate,
  InputText,
  Toggle,
  Svg
};
```

2. You can combine the import and export statement. ES6 supports directly exporting imported modules:

```js
export * from …;
```

And you can export the `default export` as `named export` like this:

```js
// @flow

export { default as Button } from './Button/Button.component';
export { default as Devider } from './DividerComponent/Divider.component';
export { default as Dropdown } from './Dropdown/Dropdown.component';
export { default as GeneralText } from './GeneralTextComponent/GeneralText.component';
export { default as IconButton } from './IconButton/IconButton.component';
export { default as InputDate } from './InputDate/InputDate.component';
export { default as InputText } from './InputText/InputText.component';
export { default as Toggle } from './ToggleComponent/Toggle.component';
export { default as Svg } from './Svg/Svg.component';
```